# Javascript generated html - P tag generates outside of A tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup form which is coded like this

```
var popup = '<div id="popup"><p id="shareHeader">Share On</p>'+
            '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="'+url+'><p>Facebook</p></a>'+
            '<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url="'+url+'><p>LinkedIn</p></a>'+
            '<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=GET%20800%20SAT&url="'+url+'><p>Twitter</p></a>'+
            '</div><div id="close">Close</div>';
```

but when it generates it moves the p tag outside the a tag like so...

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" http:="" satprepget800.com=""></a><p>Facebook</p>...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: u need to have closing " on ur url

Comment: you can't have a P tag in an A tag, P is block and A is inline. use SPAN instead of P, then use CSS to make it look good.

Comment: hehe I think I misunderstood the question..

Comment: no harm in trying; better to aim high and miss than aim low and hit. you can edit...

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'url';

var popup = '<div id="popup"><p id="shareHeader">Share On</p>'+
            '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url+'"><p>Facebook</p></a>'+
            '<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url='+url+'"><p>LinkedIn</p></a>'+
            '<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=GET%20800%20SAT&url='+url+'"><p>Twitter</p></a>'+
            '</div><div id="close">Close</div>';
```